# Error: Conversion from string "x" to type Integer is not valid. How do I turn an integer into a string?

Tags: vb.net

So I am making a program in which you can select products from a combo box, select the quantity and it will return with the price and the quantity in a list box as well as the total price. It then inputs the data in the listbox into a Microsoft Access database.

When I click the button btnOrderProducts, I receive an error that reads:

Error: Conversion from string "x" to type Integer is not valid

I am unsure what this error means and how to figure out a resolution. Changing my access database data types from integers into short texts didn't fix it, so it is something to do with the code.

[Here is an image of the form for reference](https://i.imgur.com/jTR1VPe.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnOrderProducts_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOrderProducts.Click

        Dim numberOfItems = ListBoxCart.Items.Count
        For Each item As String In ListBoxCart.Items

            Try

                cm = New OleDbCommand
                With cm
                    .Connection = cn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblOrders ([ProductName],[Quantity],[PriceEach],[TotalPrice],[Username]) VALUES (@ProductName,@Quantity,@PriceEach,@TotalPrice,@Username)"

                    prod_list = item.Split(" ").ToList
                    Dim prod_name = prod_list.ElementAt(1)
                    Dim prod_quantity = Integer.Parse(prod_list.ElementAt(0).Remove("x"))
                    Dim price_each = prod_list.ElementAt(2)

                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ProductName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, prod_name))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Quantity", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, prod_quantity))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@PriceEach", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, price_each))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TotalPrice", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Total))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, txtUsername.Text))
                    prod_list = New List(Of String)

                    cm.Parameters("@ProductName").Value = prod_name
                    cm.Parameters("@Quanity").Value = prod_quantity
                    cm.Parameters("@PriceEach").Value = price_each
                    cm.Parameters("@TotalPrice").Value = Total
                    cm.Parameters("@Username").Value = txtUsername.Text

                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = ""
                    txtQuantity.Text = ListBoxCart.Text = ""
                    txtTotalPrice.Text = ""

                    Exit Sub
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Consider also that Splitting at the space will create from "x1 iPad Case $20" an array of four strings where the price is at index 3 not 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does not remove the "x" from the string

```
Dim prod_quantity = Integer.Parse(prod_list.ElementAt(0).Remove("x"))
```

It should rather be:

```
Dim prod_quantity = Integer.Parse(prod_list.ElementAt(0).Remove(0,1))
```

But i would not recommend to concatenate the items-properties to a string and  later split the string to get the items-properties back.
Give my answer to your previous question a chance. So you will not have these problems.

Furthermore i would recommend to set `Option Strict` to `On` in the project properties.

Comment: Thanks friend! You fixed it for me <3

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the [`String.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx) method does not do what you think it does.

From the link:

> Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position, have been deleted

The "x" cannot be converted into an integer.